# Why does my Haskell program not accept standard input redirection?

Tags: haskell, terminal, command-line-arguments, readfile

I'm trying to read a file in Haskell by supplying the file name as a command line argument.
I have read that you can accomplish this by:

```
./program < input.txt
```

I wrote this code:

```
main = do
    [fileName] <- getArgs
    file <- readFile fileName
    print file
```

But I get this error: "pattern match failure in do expression". If I omit the < sign it works, is this the only way to accomplish this? I would much rather not omit it. What should I change?

Comment: The `<` symbol has absolutely nothing to do with Haskell - it is the "pipe" operator, which (is implemented by your shell, and) passes the output of one program as the *input* (not a command line argument) to the other program. Your Haskell program expects to always receive one argument and so crashes.

Comment: @user2407038 Actually, `<` is not a shell pipe, it's just input redirection. `ls -l | grep foo` would be a pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`./program < input.txt` calls the program with 0 arguments and redirects stdin to the contents of `input.txt`.

So you get a pattern matching error because `getArgs` is empty. So if you want your program to always read from stdin, don't use the command line arguments at all and read from stdin instead of a file.

If you want your program to read from stdin only if no file name was given, check the length of the arguments first and then read from the given file name or from stdin depending on that.

Comment: Thanks! :D Now I used file <- getContents instead and it worked :)

Comment: Don't check length; pattern match.

Comment: Well, pattern matching is the best way to check the length of the arguments in this case. I wouldn't say we're *not* checking length.

Answer (score 2):

If you run `./program arg` then `arg` is passed as an argument. The standard input is left on its default -- usually reading from keyboard from a terminal.

If you run `./program < filename` then no arguments are passed to the program. The standard input now is redirected so to read from file `filename`.

This is just how the OS shell works.

In Haskell, `getArgs` gets the program arguments. In the second case, they are empty, and `[fileName] <- getArgs` fails with your runtime error.